# File Uploaded Through FTP and automatically Processed by Php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just want to Send a file On the web server through FTP. and what i want mainly is i have a file on which i have some code for processing this file(it will be Csv) and i want to process this code automatically after uploading through FTP.Can any body please help. i have no idea about this. is there any FTp functions which will work for this.please let me know,

Comment: Well you could have some kind of file system watcher run by cronjob, but why not just upload via http post to php directly?

Comment: I dont want to use crone job. it should have immediate response after uploading through FTP.

Comment: Well, some script has to check if any file has been uploaded to the server. If you upload the file with php, after upload you can start processing the csv file (in the same script).

Comment: #machineaddict :: i have done it with PHP. but now my client also wants it with FTP upload, how will the server know that it has a new  file. thhis is the main point. i have searched and found Inotify,  will it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install a Grunt watch task on the server which will watch for changes in the FTP folder. It's easy to install via Node's NPM.

http://gruntjs.com

This will immediately trigger a script including PHP CLI scripts to post-process your uploaded files, and is easy to configure yet powerful in scope.